# "At" vs. "in" followed by a city name

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, at-in

Is it correct to use "at" followed by a place name (city, town, village, etc.)? I've been seeing phrases like "a hotel at Las Vegas" or "she was living at London" quite a lot recently. Is this a difference between British and US English, perhaps?

Comment: This looks like it should probably be migrated to [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: That usage of "at" is common in Indian English.

Comment: Normal British usage would be "*in* a place"; e.g. *in London*; *in Las Vegas*.

Comment: Thanks, Trevor. Thing is, I can't find if this is an Americanism or just substandard. Carlo, Didn't know it is common in Indian Eng, but I've seen this usage a lot in American publications. Mat, don't take the trouble. Cheers.

Comment: @Ana: In America you would normally be *in* a City, but you can also be *at* work, a friend's house, or *at* something which is close to, but not inside a city, such as the music festival *at* Glastonbury in the UK.

Answer (score 19):

The choice of *in* or *at* with a city depends on how speakers conceive that city in the context of the statement they are making.

If the city is conceived as a two-dimensional place in which to live and work, then *in* is the usual preposition. If, on the other hand, the city is conceived as a single point rather than as a place with dimensions, then *at* is the common choice.

This explains the difference between sentences such as:

> I live in Frankfurt. /  The plane stops at Frankfurt on the way to Seoul.
>
> The meeting took place at Potsdam. / There was an explosion in Potsdam yesterday.

On this basis, the expressions *a hotel at Las Vegas* and *she was living at London* are  the idiosyncratic choices of individual speakers. I am not aware of any significant patterns of difference between BE and AE speakers.

Comment: Only two-dimensional? I usually consider places to live and work as having three dimensions …

Comment: you forget about time, @JanusBahsJacquet

Answer (score 3):

We use the word "At" for a stop on a journey:
We stopped at a nice village.
The train to Manchester stops at Birmingham.