# "died at New York"

Tags: prepositions, historical-change, language-change, twentieth-century-english

While doing archival work I bumped into a few instances where the awkward verbiage "died at New York" appeared. Research using Google Books led me to these examples from over a century ago:

> died at New York City, October 8 1879 [[1]](https://books.google.com/books?id=wekpAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA938&dq=%22died%20at%20New%20York%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwid4qn4tLiCAxUmGTQIHZiPAdUQ6AF6BAglEAI#v=onepage&q=%22died%20at%20New%20York%22&f=false)
> Colonel Henry Steel Olcott married, in Trinity Church, at New Rochelle, New York, April 26, 1860 (same source two pages down)
> Commodore Alfred Van Santvoord, Son of..., was born at Utica, New York, January 23, 1819 (same source 2 pages further down)

There seem to be a lot of similar examples from that period of time, just to list a few more: [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=xy0bAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA257&dq=%22died+at+New+York%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwid4qn4tLiCAxUmGTQIHZiPAdUQ6AF6BAgtEAI#v=onepage&q=%22died%20at%20New%20York%22&f=false), [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=UxOgAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA413&dq=%22died%20at%20New%20York%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwid4qn4tLiCAxUmGTQIHZiPAdUQ6AF6BAgvEAI#v=onepage&q=%22died%20at%20New%20York%22&f=false), [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=txg-AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA21&dq=%22died%20at%20New%20York%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwid4qn4tLiCAxUmGTQIHZiPAdUQ6AF6BAggEAI#v=onepage&q=%22died%20at%20New%20York%22&f=false), [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=b6AhB-PTzMYC&pg=PA1213&dq=%22died%20at%20New%20York%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwid4qn4tLiCAxUmGTQIHZiPAdUQ6AF6BAgeEAI#v=onepage&q=%22died%20at%20New%20York%22&f=false), [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=JAL30Bv_NS4C&pg=PA371&dq=%22died%20at%20New%20York%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwid4qn4tLiCAxUmGTQIHZiPAdUQ6AF6BAgYEAI#v=onepage&q=%22died%20at%20New%20York%22&f=false). "At New York" or "at" a city just grinds on my ear and sounds like something an English learner would say. Why did they use "at" in this period of time? And was it a common choice of preposition to go with a city back in the day? If there has indeed been a shift, when did we start to say "in New York"?

Comment: I think it's just an old fashioned usage. No reason for it.

Comment: The OED seems to have examples up to the 19th century e.g. 1849 "The Parliament met at Edinburgh." It says "With proper names of places: particularly used of towns (with many exceptions, such as London, New York, etc.), and that in which the speaker lives (if of any size); (also) of small islands. Cf. on the Isle of Wight, on Inchkeith, at St. Helena, at Malta, at the English Lakes, at the Cape. Formerly used more widely: at Ireland, at London." You'd need a more thorough study to trace the precise use through history; the OED warns "a classification of its uses is very difficult. "

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Usage of 'at' and 'in' for cities](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125983/usage-of-at-and-in-for-cities), ["At" vs. "in" followed by a city name](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124755/), ["Born in a City" or "Born at a City"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/506531/), [Correct usage of ‘on’, ‘at’ and ‘in’](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/757).